# Unity android banner ad issue after level restart

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, banner

in my game when character die i want to show banner and hide it when player press restart button. Its work fine but after first reset when i want to show banner i get error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.showBanner ()

so should i request banner after every game restart? it wont be too laggy?

i tried also to attach `DontDestroyOnLoad (this);` to object which has my ad scripts but it didnt work.

My restart button: `Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);`

AD Script `

```
private BannerView bannerView;
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
private static string outputMessage = "";

public static string OutputMessage
{
    set { outputMessage = value; }
}


private void RequestBanner()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = "myai";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
    #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

    // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
    bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);
    // Register for ad events.
    bannerView.AdLoaded += HandleAdLoaded;
    bannerView.AdFailedToLoad += HandleAdFailedToLoad;
    bannerView.AdOpened += HandleAdOpened;
    bannerView.AdClosing += HandleAdClosing;
    bannerView.AdClosed += HandleAdClosed;
    bannerView.AdLeftApplication += HandleAdLeftApplication;
    // Load a banner ad.
    bannerView.LoadAd(createAdRequest());
}

private void RequestInterstitial()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_ANDROID_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
    #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

    // Create an interstitial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
    // Register for ad events.
    interstitial.AdLoaded += HandleInterstitialLoaded;
    interstitial.AdFailedToLoad += HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad;
    interstitial.AdOpened += HandleInterstitialOpened;
    interstitial.AdClosing += HandleInterstitialClosing;
    interstitial.AdClosed += HandleInterstitialClosed;
    interstitial.AdLeftApplication += HandleInterstitialLeftApplication;
    GoogleMobileAdsDemoHandler handler = new GoogleMobileAdsDemoHandler();
    interstitial.SetInAppPurchaseHandler(handler);
    // Load an interstitial ad.
    interstitial.LoadAd(createAdRequest());
}

// Returns an ad request with custom ad targeting.
private AdRequest createAdRequest()
{
    return new AdRequest.Builder()
            .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
            .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
            .AddKeyword("game")
            .SetGender(Gender.Male)
            .SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
            .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
            .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
            .Build();

}

private void ShowInterstitial()
{
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        print("Interstitial is not ready yet.");
    }
}

#region Banner callback handlers

public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleAdLoaded event received.");
}

public void HandleAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: " + args.Message);
}

public void HandleAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleAdOpened event received");
}

void HandleAdClosing(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleAdClosing event received");
}

public void HandleAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleAdClosed event received");
}

public void HandleAdLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleAdLeftApplication event received");
}

#endregion

#region Interstitial callback handlers

public void HandleInterstitialLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleInterstitialLoaded event received.");
}

public void HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad event received with message: " + args.Message);
}

public void HandleInterstitialOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleInterstitialOpened event received");
}

void HandleInterstitialClosing(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleInterstitialClosing event received");
}

public void HandleInterstitialClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleInterstitialClosed event received");
}

public void HandleInterstitialLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleInterstitialLeftApplication event received");
}

#endregion
```

`
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a plugin of Appodeal.